# Datalab Jupyter notebook logs

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I have just started working with google cloud datalab. I would like to inspect the logs generated by jupyter-notebook. I can see the process running on the instance, but cannot find where the logs go (either locally on the instance or in stackdriver logging)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ssh into the VM and run the `docker logs ${containerId}` command.

Bash command to get the logs for the currently running datalab instance:

```
docker logs $(docker ps | grep "gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab" | awk '{print $1}')
```